# fiddler custom rules script: oSession object is undeclared

Tags: javascript, fiddler

I am trying to write some custom script for fiddler similar to this:

```
if (oSession.uriContains(".css")){
 oSession["ui-color"]="orange"; 
 oSession["ui-bold"]="true";
 oSession.oRequest.FailSession(404, "Blocked", "Fiddler blocked CSS file");
}
```

But I get compilation failure due to: Variable 'oSession' has not been declared. Has anyone ran into this problem before and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you put the code in question? Did you put it inside the **BeforeRequest** function? Did you change the name of the parameter in the function declaration?

The declaration should look like this:

```
 static function OnBeforeRequest(oSession: Session) {
 // your code here...
```